# Как я могу стилизовать псевдоэлемент в качестве заголовка абзаца?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-selectors

Мы используем Markdown (Kramdown) для создания статического веб-сайта. Для инфобоксов мы можем аннотировать абзацы и получить следующие результаты:

```
{:.note .icon-check title="This is a title"}
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

А это преобразованный HTML:

```
<p class="note icon-check" title="This is a title">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</p>
```

CSS

```
p.note {
  &::before {
    float: right;
  }

  position: relative;

  &[title]::after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.icon::before {
  content: "@";
}
```

Поскольку мы используем `icon fonts Icomoon`, в которых содержимое установлено в `:before`, заголовок должен быть в `:after`.

- мы не будем менять `Iconfont`, поэтому иконка должен оставаться в
  `:before`
- нет дополнительной отвлекающей разметки в markdown, поэтому нет
  HTML-оболочки
- нет Javascript

Можно установить абсолютное позиционирование для заголовка, но это будет слишком близко для `paragraph-text`, так как `margin` не может быть установлен.

Здесь [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsjL9zrx/1/)

Теперь, как можно стилизовать поле с помощью `:after` в качестве заголовка вверху, который также хорошо выглядит, когда заголовок не установлен?

```css
main {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  place-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

p.note {
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

p.note::before {
  margin: auto 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  float: right;
}

p.note[title]::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0;
  left: 1em;
}

.icon::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "@";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>

    <p class="note icon" title="This is a title">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
    </p>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I style a pseudo-element as the title of a paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65242345/7394871) от участника  [@nonsensation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11341498/nonsensation).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65242345/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Безумная идея с использованием `shape-outside`. Трюк состоит в том, чтобы использовать :before для заголовка, где вы применяете `float`, и после для иконки, имеющего `position: absolute`, тогда `shape-outside` создаст определенную форму, чтобы имитировать поведение float вокруг значка.

```css
main {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:justify;
}

p.note {
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

p.note::after {
  margin: auto 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  position:absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 0.5em;
}


p.note[title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  display:block;
  height:3.5em;
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  shape-outside:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,calc(100% - 3em) 100%,calc(100% - 3em) calc(100% - 2em),0 calc(100% - 2em));
  /* To illustrate the shape */
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0.3) 0 0) top/100% calc(100% - 2em) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0.3) 0 0) bottom right/3em 3em no-repeat;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   /**/
}

.icon::after {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "@";
}

.icon:not([title])::after {
  display:none;
}

.icon:not([title])::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "@";
  margin: auto 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <p class="note icon" title="This is a title">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
  </p>

</main>

<main>

  <p class="note icon" >
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
  </p>

</main>
```

Или основная идея, как показано ниже:

```css
main {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:justify;
}

p.note {
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

p.note::before {
  margin: auto 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  float: right;
}

p.note[title]::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  right:2em;
  text-align:center;
}
p.note[title] {
  padding-top:2em;
}

.icon::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "@";
}
```

```html
<main>

  <p class="note icon" title="This is a title">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
  </p>

</main>

<main>

  <p class="note icon" >
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
  </p>

</main>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242850/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

поскольку [grid](https://jsfiddle.net/hcb7agow/2/) не помогает, давайте вернемся во времени с помощью display: table и display: table-caption, чтобы добавить еще один ответ и посмотреть, может ли это сработать и для вас;)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 50%;
  min-width:450px;
  display: block;
  place-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

p.note {
  font-size:clamp(12px, 4vw, 30px);
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: table;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
p.note::before {
  margin: auto 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  float: right;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:tomato;
}
p.note[title]::after {
  content: attr(title);
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-caption;
  margin-bottom: -1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.icon::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "@";
  line-height: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<main>
 
 <p class="note icon" title="This is a title">
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quidem non placeat quibusdam velit, dicta adipisci saepe magnam fuga debitis qui, minima, eius error laboriosam distinctio eos natus et!
 </p>
 
</main>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243307/7394871) от участника  [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus).</sub>